# jquery: using uploadify invisibly

Tags: jquery, uploadify

i am using the uploadify plugin and was wondering, can it be used as invisible object? 
which means keeping it invisible and controlling it by jquery code only, like opening the file dialog, starting the upload - or does it need to be visible for clicking on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No – the File Dialog can only be opened as a result of a user event (in this case click) *inside* the Flash document. You cannot trigger this from JavaScript. – This is due to the Flash security model surrounding the File System.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it hidden then is uploadify necessary? You can take a look at this "ajax" like file upload with iframes which can be easily hidden

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/